# Why won't my TV see the Raspberry Pi 4 as a source

Tags: raspbian, noobs, pi-4, raspberry-pi-desktop

I recently got a Raspberry Pi 4B and i used a 128GB MicroSD card and copied over the files from Noobs 3.2.1. I connected the MicroHDMI > HDMI to my TV and connected the power adapter and turned it on. My TV (multiple TVs tested, Samsung and Toshiba) doesn't see the Pi, and says "No Source Found".

I can see the Rasp Pi has a steady red LED on and the green LED is blinking 4 times and pauses and blinks again and continues this step.

Please help me resolve the issue. If any other information I need to provide, let me know.

P.s. I don't even see the rainbow screen, the TV just doesn't see the Pi at all.

Comment: As joan points out, the steady pattern of green blinks indicates a problem.

Comment: @goldilocks Thanks, but after reviewing the docs it looks like start.elf not found. Didn't find any docs on how to resolve it. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the green LED is blinking 4 times and pauses and blinks again and continues this step.

As you have seen this indicates a boot problem, namely that "start.elf is not found".

> Didn't find any docs on how to resolve it.

I imagine that is a bit inscrutable if you don't know what it is referring to. `start.elf` is required to be in the boot partition, which is the first one, relatively small and VFAT formatted.

If `start.elf` is really there, it could be that it is not a recent enough version to run on a Pi 4. I don't know whether that is a potential issue or not, but you could try creating a fresh card from a new image and see if that works.

If it is *not* there, then the card was not created correctly and you will have to try that again.

However, there is another possibility if it is there: The card is not formatted correctly.  It needs to be MBR style (aka DOS) formatted.  You have said nothing about how you made the card beyond "copied the files over".

Comment: Thanks, I used SD Card Formatter as most raspberry pi docs online recommends. I will try to re-do the steps again and see if it works. I also noticed the pi 4 doesn't need start.elf file which I didn't find anywhere in the extracted file.

Comment: Update: I downloaded Rasbian image and burnt it in the memory card, connected the pi to my TV, the green light was steady on for about 15 seconds and no it's completely off and only shows the red LED light.

Comment: That sounds like it is booting properly. Try adding `hdmi_safe=1` to `config.txt` in the boot partition.  This may lower the resolution but it is the best bet to get it working so you can see if it does work.  Note if the TV isn't HDMI (ie, you are using an adapter cable), there are some problems associated with that.

Comment: It's direct MicroHDMI -> HDMI. I will try that and restart the Pi and see if it works. Thanks

Comment: That actually did the trick!!! the `hdmi_safe=1` uncommenting worked.

Comment: See here for more about that: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md ...Scroll down to the bit about `hdmi_safe`.  It includes a bunch of settings not all of which may be desirable (eg. 720p resolution); *probably* the only one you actually need is `hdmi_force_hotplug=1`.  You could try just that and `hdmi_mode=16` (1080p @ 60Hz).

Comment: The resolution is too big, I guess I can use `16` to make it smaller. Great stuff. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You will not get anything at all until the Pi4B has successfully booted.

Your Pi4B has not booted successfully.

Go through this [Pi4B specific boot sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151#p1485558).

If that does not resolve the issue go through the [full boot sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151#p437084).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. From this message `If the green LED blinks with a repeating four blink pattern then the bootloader is running correctly, and indicating that start.elf has not been found.` I didn't see any solution on how to add it to my Pi.